# Symfony2: how to display a flash message which was generated in a subcontroller

Tags: symfony

I am trying to set a flash message in a subcontroller (a controller which is embedded in the view via {% render "...Bundle:Subscribe:widget" %}), however the flash message is not outputted in my main template. any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you solved this? Could you please show some code? Anyway for embedded controllers Symfony only gets the response content. I think it's an hard thing to do...

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not solve this by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing it via javascript/jQuery:

```
var messages = "";
// collect flash messages of all widgets (=subcontroller actions)
$('.flash-message').each(function(){
    messages += $(this).html()+"<br/>";
    $(this).html("");
});
// set messages into the "flash message container"
if(messages){
    $('#flash-message span').html(messages);
}
// show the messages
if($('#flash-message span').html().trim()){
    $('#flash-message').hide().delay(20).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The flash message is meant for the "next" load. If you want it on the current page where the embedded controller call was made, you should pass the message some other way, like through a session variable or create an internal messaging system for this.